# how do you escape a dot?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace the `.pdf` extension in a string with `/id.jpg`

```
preg_replace('/.pdf/', '/id.jpg', $url);
```

when I output the `$url` nothing is changed. I think I need to escape the dot in `.pdf` or maybe escape in the `/` in `/id.jpg`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a backslash to make sure you correctly match the dot: `\.`

Also, you say, "when I output the `$url` nothing is changed." `preg_replace()` does not modify the `$subject` parameter. To store the new value in `$url`, you need to do an assignment:

```
$url = preg_replace('/\.pdf/', '/id.jpg', $url);
```

Comment: you mean like this? `preg_replace('/\.pdf/', '/id.jpg', $url);`

Comment: @user962449 don't you generally have to escape everything with a \ ?